# MySQL very big table - creating sort index for over 24 hours

Tags: mysql, sorting, indexing

I have a very big MySQL table (68 million rows),

and I am trying to keep one row per minute using the following query:

```
    delete bt     
    from table1 bt 
    join          (select date, min(time) as time
       from table1           
    group by date, hour(time), minute(time)          
    ) 
    btt          
    on btt.date = bt.date 
and hour(bt.time) = hour(btt.time) 
and minute(bt.time) = minute(btt.time) 
and btt.time <> bt.time
```

my table has the following columns

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date           | varchar(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time           | varchar(12) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| gmt_offset     | varchar(2)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| type           | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| yield_b        | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| yield_d        | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The query is running for over 24 hours, and when I run

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

the State says

```
Creating sort index
```

Is it normal for such a query to take so long ? Is there some way to speed things up ? Thanks !

EDIT :

Gordon's answer was right, only had a minor mistake in one line. Here is the correct query that indeed works MUCH faster than the previous one :

```
create table temp_table1 as
    select t.*
    from (select t1.*,
                 (@rn := if(@prevd = date and minute(time) = @prevm, @rn + 1,
                            if(@prevd := date, if(@prevm := minute(time), 1, 1), 1)
                           )
                 ) as seqnum
          from table1 t1 cross join
               (select @rn := 0, @prevd := 0, @prevm := 0) vars
          order by date, time
         ) t
     where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Please clarify.  It looks from your query like you're attempting to delete all rows except the first (smallest value of `time`) row in each distinct minute. Is that correct?  Please show your indexes. Is there any reason you have to separate `date` and `time`? If you combined them into a single column, gave it a `DATETIME` data type, and indexed it, you'd be well on your way to an efficient solution.

Comment: One more question: are the `id` values monotone increasing with date+time? That is, if one `id` is greater than another, is it a guarantee that its date+time is at the same time as, or later than, the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of deleting a bunch of rows, create a temporary table with the data you want, then truncate the original table and insert it back in:

```
create table temp_table1 as
    select t.*
    from (select t1.*,
                 (@rn := if(@prevd <> date or minute(time) <> @prevm, 1,
                            if(@prevd := date, if(@prevm := minute(time), 1, 1), 1)
                           )
                 ) as seqnum
          from table1 t1 cross join
               (select @rn := 0, @prevd := 0, @prevm := 0) vars
          order by date, time
         ) t
     where seqnum = 1;


truncate table table1;

insert into table1(col1, . . ., coln)
    select col1, . . . , coln
    from temp_table1;
```

The first query has a subquery that enumerates the rows within a minute.  Then, only the first is kept.  This is then inserted into an empty version of the table.  Of course, test the results from the first query before truncating the original table (and I would copy over the data somewhere else, just in case).

Comment: Awesome. thanks a lot! I don't need to insert seqnum as well, right ? What is the meaning of this variable ? Some kind of an index ?

Comment: @adrCoder . . . seqnum is enumerating the rows in the original table that occur within the same minute.  The logic takes the first one.

Comment: Hi Gordon. Your solution doesn't work. It basically puts seqnum = 1 to every row and doesn't delete any rows.. can you please take a look ? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Gordon's answer is good. Here's another approach, that will work if your ids are monotone increasing with time.

First, grab yourself the `id` values of the first observations in each distinct minute.

```
SELECT MIN(id) As first_id_in_minute
  FROM table1 
 GROUP BY date, HOUR(time), MINUTE(time)
```

Those are the `id` values for the rows you want to keep.

Then delete the rest of the rows. Use `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` to get the nonmatching rows. That's probably faster than `IS NOT IN(...)`.

```
 DELETE a 
   FROM table1 AS a
   LEFT JOIN  (
                   SELECT MIN(id) As first_id_in_minute
                     FROM table1 
                 GROUP BY date, HOUR(time), MINUTE(time)
             ) AS b ON a.id = b.first_id_in_minute
 WHERE b.first_id_in_minute IS NULL
 LIMIT 1000
```

I put in the LIMIT 1000 to keep down the size of each DELETE operation.  You should repeat this query until it declares that no rows were affected.

Try putting a compound index on `(date, time, id)` to accelerate the `MIN() ... GROUP BY` part of this.

Like Gordon suggested, try this on a copy of the table, eh?

Comment: Hi Ollie. Indeed in my data time is increasing with the ID so what you're saying is a very good idea. Thanks